# local apache2 adds trailing slash

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am currently trying to get a webpage of mine running on my local machine. Strangely though, albeit I do use the exact same Directives and RewriteRules, what works on my server, does not work on my local machine.

What happens is that every request to a file is handled as a request to a directory, e.g.

```
http://mysite/img/logo.png -> http://mysite/img/logo.png/
http://mysite/css/main.css -> http://mysite/css/main.css/
http://mysite/subfolder/page.html -> http://mysite/subfolder/page.html/
```

My Directives are:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/url/to/site
<Directory /var/www/url/to/site/>
  Options none +FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

My Rewrite Rules are:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(\/)?$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^/?(natur)?(wohl)?klang/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(\/)?$ /$1$2klang/$3.html
```

Comment: Those rewrite rules don't do redirects.  It must be something else.  Don't forget to look for `.htaccess` files or switch `AllowOverride` to none.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by changing the Directory Directive from

```
<Directory /var/www/url/to/site/>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/url/to/site>
```

(note the missing trailing slash).